# In Shopify, how do I output multi-word product tags?

Tags: shopify

I'm creating a breadcrumb in Shopify, and using filtered_tag_array.first to display product tags in the breadcrumb. However, some of my product tags are more than one word - for example "for the buffet". Using the "filtered_tag_array.first" code, only the word "for" displays if I am pulling up "for the buffet". One option that works is changing the product tags to have dashes in them, but that doesn't look as nice in the breadcrumb. Is there a way I can code it so I can display multi-word product tags in the breadcrumb without adding dashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use dashes in your product tags and [replace](https://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/filters/string-filters#replace) them with spaces in the breadcrumb.

E.g.

```
{{ tag | replace: '-', ' ' }}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. For the three word product tag "for the buffet", here is the code I used to make it render properly in the breadcrumb:

{% if filtered_tag_array.first == 'for'%}{{ 'for' | append: ' the buffet' }}{%else%}{{ filtered_tag_array.first }}{% endif %}

Comment: Is there a better answer?